# How to deal with @BeforeEach @AfterEach for all test except one

Tags: unit-testing, junit5

A test class has several tests, each one depends on the `@BeforeEach` and is teared down by `@AfterEach`, except one black sheep!

How to deal with this in Juni5?
Is it legit to just have `@AfterEach` and `@BeforeEach` do an extra round for nothing?

Comment: Did you consider moving that test to a different class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If moving the test to another class is not practical, you can use a @Nested class to solve this. @BeforeEach and @AfterEach will be executed only for those tests defined inside. Here is an example:

```
@Test
void oneTEstWithNoBeforeAfterEach() {}

@Nested
class allOtherTestsGoHere {

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {}

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {}

    @Test
    void testOne() {}

    @Test
    void testTwo() {}
}
```